# Перечислить экспортируемые функции C++

Tags: c++, extern

Как можно получить список экспортируемых функций/методов из dll, написанной на c++?
Мне интересен сам алгоритм, а не конкретная программа.

Comment: Он хранится в таблице экспорта. Таблицу можно отыскать, ознакомившись с форматом файлов Portable Executable.

Comment: а чего так много проголосовавших за закрытие? отличный ведь вопрос (в ms/windows подобная информация наверняка довольно муторно извлекается). разве что дубликат найдётся. но дубликат, судя по всему, никто не искал.